# Get data from file - Buffered Reader

Tags: java, twitter, bufferedreader, filereader

I would just have the id, the content and the hashtag and time of every tweet in a text file, and I dont know how to store infomration in lists of tweet,
I created a tweet class as follows:

```
            public class Tweet {
private String type;
private String origin;  
private String tweetText;
private String url;
private String tweetID;
private String tweetDate;
private int retCount;
private String favourit;
private String mEntities;
private String hashtags;

public Tweet(String tweetID,String origin) {
    this.tweetID = tweetID;
    this.origin = origin;
}

public Tweet(String type, String origin, String tweetText, String url, String tweetID, String tweetDate, int retCount, String favourit, String mEntities, String hashtags) {
    this.type = type;
    this.origin = origin;
    this.tweetText = tweetText;
    this.url = url;
    this.tweetID = tweetID;
    this.tweetDate = tweetDate;
    this.retCount = retCount;
    this.favourit = favourit;
    this.mEntities = mEntities;
    this.hashtags = hashtags;
}




public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getOrigin() {
    return origin;
}

public void setOrigin(String origin) {
    this.origin = origin;
}

public String getTweetText() {
    return tweetText;
}

public void setTweetText(String tweetText) {
    this.tweetText = tweetText;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getTweetID() {
    return tweetID;
}

public void setTweetID(String tweetID) {
    this.tweetID = tweetID;
}

public String getTweetDate() {
    return tweetDate;
}

public void setTweetDate(String tweetDate) {
    this.tweetDate = tweetDate;
}

public int getRetCount() {
    return retCount;
}

public void setRetCount(int retCount) {
    this.retCount = retCount;
}

public String getFavourit() {
    return favourit;
}

public void setFavourit(String favourit) {
    this.favourit = favourit;
}

public String getmEntities() {
    return mEntities;
}

public void setmEntities(String mEntities) {
    this.mEntities = mEntities;
}

public String getHashtags() {
    return hashtags;
}

public void setHashtags(String hashtags) {
    this.hashtags = hashtags;
}
```

and my data file has the following format:

```
             ***
             ***
             Type:status
             Origin: Here's link to listen live to our discussion of  #debtceiling #politics : 
             Text: Here's link to listen live to our discussion of   : 
             URL: 
             ID: 96944336150867968
             Time: Fri Jul 29 09:05:05 CDT 2011
             RetCount: 0
             Favorite: false
             MentionedEntities: 
             Hashtags:  debtceiling politics
             ***
             ***
             Type:status
             Origin: Now we're talking #debtceiling w/ Dick Polman @NewsWorksWHYY @PhillyInquirer & Bill Galston @BrookingsInst @NoLabelsOrg 
            Text: Now we're talking  w/ Dick Polman   & Bill Galston   
            URL: 
            ID: 96943803600089088
            Time: Fri Jul 29 09:02:58 CDT 2011
            RetCount: 1
            Favorite: false
            MentionedEntities: 136337303 151106990 14495726 15161791 
            Hashtags:  debtceiling
            ***
            ***
```

I want to read this file and stock information into lists, i begin with this code, but i dont know how to solve that

```
            public static List<String> readTweets(File file) throws IOException {
    List<String> tweets = new ArrayList<String>();
    //logger.info("Read tweets from {}", file.getAbsolutePath());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    String[] fields;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        fields = line.split(",");
        if (fields.length > 1)
            tweets.add(fields[1]);
    }
    return tweets;
}
```

Comment: why do you split it by "," ?
as far as I can see you have to read every line and after you reach ***/n*** you store the information in the Tweet class then add it to the list

Comment: when i do fields = line.split("\n"); it gives me []

Comment: just write out line to the console and tell me what it prints out
I believe that will give you an empty array because the line won't have /n at the end

Comment: while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   fields = line.split("\n");
   if (fields.length > 1)
    tweets.add(fields[1]);
  }
  return tweets;
 }  it gives me []

Comment: but you don't have to split the line. if you are getting the data from the file by line, then you don't have to split it by "/n"

Comment: So how can i get each tweet alone  if i dont need to spline the line

Comment: I'll try to write an asnwer for this

Comment: Your Tweet class is not finished yet. I am writing an answer for you now, do you want me to add all the missing methods in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of the code you are experimenting with, this is what I would do:

```
public static List<String> readTweets(File file) throws IOException {
    List<String> tweets = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
    for(int i = 0; i < lines.length(); i++){
        String line = lines.get(i);
        String[] part = line.split(",");
        if(part.length < 1) tweets.add(part[i]);
   }
}
```

But, if I wrote an application that was purely for printing the contents of tweets into the console, here's how I'd do it:

*TweetReader.java*

```
package Testers;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TweetReader {

    public static List<Tweet> readTweets(File file) throws IOException {
        boolean processEnd = false;
        String type = "";
        String origin = "";
        String tweetText = "";
        String url = "";
        String tweetID = "";
        String tweetDate = "";
        int retCount = 0;
        String favourite = "";
        String mEntities = "";
        String hashTags = "";
        List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());
        for(int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++){
            String line = lines.get(i);
            line = line.trim();
            if(line.equals("***")){
                if(processEnd){
                    Tweet tweet = new Tweet(type, origin, tweetText, url, tweetID, tweetDate, retCount, favourite, mEntities, hashTags);
                    tweets.add(tweet);
                    processEnd = false;
                }else processEnd = true;
            }else{
                if(line.contains(":")){
                    String header = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(":"));
                    //System.out.println(header); //You can uncomment this for troubleshooting
                    if(header.equals("Type")) type = line.substring(line.length() > 5 ? 5 : line.length());
                    else if(header.equals("Origin")) origin = line.substring(line.length() > 8 ? 8 : line.length());
                    else if(header.equals("Text")) tweetText = line.substring(line.length() > 6 ? 6 : line.length());
                    else if(header.equals("URL")) url = line.substring(line.length() > 5 ? 5 : line.length());
                    else if(header.equals("ID")) tweetID = line.substring(line.length() > 4 ? 4 : line.length());
                    else if(header.equals("Time")) tweetDate = line.substring(line.length() > 6 ? 6 : line.length());
                    else if(header.equals("RetCount")) retCount = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.length() > 10 ? 10 : line.length()));
                    else if(header.equals("Favorite")) favourite = line.substring(line.length() > 11 ? 11 : line.length());
                    else if(header.equals("MentionedEntities")) mEntities = line.substring(line.length() > 19 ? 19 : line.length());
                    else if(header.equals("Hashtags")) hashTags = line.substring(line.length() > 10 ? 10 : line.length());
                    else throw new IOException("Line cannot be identified as part of a tweet:" + line);
                }else throw new IOException("Line cannot be processed:" + line);
            }
       }
        return tweets;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        File log = new File("log.txt");
        List<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
        try {
            File f = new File(".").getAbsoluteFile();
            File[] array = f.listFiles();
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                File tweet = array[i];  
                if(tweet.isFile() && !tweet.getName().contains("log.txt") && !tweet.getName().contains(".jar")){
                    log("Reading file: " + tweet.getAbsolutePath(), log);
                    List<Tweet> tweetlist = readTweets(tweet);
                    tweets.addAll(tweetlist);
                }   
            }
            System.out.println("Reading tweets now");
            for(int i = 0; i < tweets.size(); i++){
                Tweet t = tweets.get(i);
                log("Type = " + t.getType(), log);
                log("Origin = " + t.getOrigin(), log);
                log("Text = " + t.getTweetText(), log);
                log("URL = " + t.getURL(), log);
                log("ID = " + t.getTweetID(), log);
                log("Date = " + t.getTweetDate(), log);
                log("Ret count = " + t.getRetCount(), log);
                log("Favourite = " + t.getFavourite(), log);
                log("Mentioned entities = " + t.getMentionedEntities(), log);
                log("Hashtags = " + t.getHashtags(), log);
                log("Tweet finished", log);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log(e, log);
        } 
        log("Finished reading tweets.", log);
    }

    private static void log(IOException e, File log) {
        log(e.getMessage(), log);
        StackTraceElement[] array = e.getStackTrace();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            log("        " + array[i], log);
        }
    }

    private static void log(String string, File log) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(log, true));
            writer.write(string);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

*Tweet.java*

```
package Testers;

public class Tweet {
private String type;
private String origin;  
private String tweetText;
private String url;
private String tweetID;
private String tweetDate;
private int retCount;
private String favourit;
private String mEntities;
private String hashtags;

public Tweet(String tweetID,String origin) {
    this.tweetID = tweetID;
    this.origin = origin;
}

public Tweet(String type, String origin, String tweetText, String url, String tweetID, String tweetDate, int retCount, String favourit, String mEntities, String hashtags) {
    this.type = type;
    this.origin = origin;
    this.tweetText = tweetText;
    this.url = url;
    this.tweetID = tweetID;
    this.tweetDate = tweetDate;
    this.retCount = retCount;
    this.favourit = favourit;
    this.mEntities = mEntities;
    this.hashtags = hashtags;
}




public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public String getOrigin(){
    return origin;
}

public String getTweetText(){
    return tweetText;
}

public String getURL(){
    return url;
}

public String getTweetID(){
    return tweetID;
}

public String getTweetDate(){
    return tweetDate;
}

public int getRetCount(){
    return retCount;
}

public String getFavourite(){
    return favourit;
}

public String getMentionedEntities(){
    return mEntities;
}

public String getHashtags(){
    return hashtags;
}

}
```

Comment: I have compiled both classes and put it as an application. Works perfectly.

Comment: no problems. If you need more help with reading files, working out date, etc I have written a library called [Shared Packages](https://github.com/JD9999/Shared-Packages). I am actually updating it at the moment.

Comment: Please can i ask you an other question ?

Comment: If you want to, go ahead!

Comment: I try to read multiple files from directory then call the readtweets function for each one, but it stopped after reading the first file, and shows me error in this line : else throw new IOException("Line cannot be identified as part of a tweet:" + line);

Comment: I read it with         File dir = new File(target_dir);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
       
        for (File f : files) {
            if(f.isFile()) {List<Tweet> tweets = readTweets(f);

Comment: Can you paste the exception on pastebin or email it to jdouglass6@me.com? (my e-mail address) so I can see the problem? Also post the contents of the file and see if the file causing the error is the only file that causes the error

Comment: Ok i'll send you an email

Comment: I had a look. The syntax is URL: url. You just have url as your line.

Comment: Edited to add logging to an external source. Also made sure code does not scan any jar file or the log file.

Answer (score 0):

```
//global attribute
List<Tweet> tweetList = new ArrayList<>();

String line = "";
String[] fields;
while (line != null) {
   line = reader.readLine();
   line = reader.readLine();
   //these two are for ***
   for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
      line = reader.readLine();
      tweets.add(line);
   // these are for the other data
   }
   Tweet tweet = createTweetFromList(tweets);
   tweetList.add(tweet);
}
```

Comment: so tweets must have as size 10 elements, and createTweetFromList will define for each element a tweet attribute ?  Ok i'll try that

Comment: no, it doesn't matter the size. the reason why I go from 0 to 10 is because in the file I get 10 type of data for a single tweet

Comment: is gives me this error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3204)
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3175)
 at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:246)
 at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:220)
 at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:212)
 at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:443)